# Magento: Retrieve a list of Groups from a Attribute Set

Tags: magento

I need to retrive a list of all groups of a certain attribute Set, given by the ID or name for example via API.

To do so, I've checked the API here (http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeSet/productAttributeSet.html) but it seems there's no way to list groups, only create, update and delete is possible.

What can I do to get the id of a certain group?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1PortTypeClient mage_client= AttributeGroup;

        MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.CatalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1GetListRequest nn = new MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.CatalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1GetListRequest();

        MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.FrameworkFilter filter = new MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.FrameworkFilter();
        MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.FrameworkFilter[] filters = new MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.FrameworkFilter[1];
        filter.field = "attribute_set_id";
        filter.value = "31";
        filter.conditionType = "eq";
        filters[0] = filter;
        //MNC_Product_Sync.MagentoService.FrameworkFilter filter1 = new MNC_Product_Sync.MagentoService.FrameworkFilter();                
        MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.FrameworkSearchFilterGroup fg = new MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.FrameworkSearchFilterGroup();
        fg.filters = filters;
        MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.FrameworkSearchFilterGroup[] fgg = new MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.FrameworkSearchFilterGroup[1];
        fgg[0] = fg;
        MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.FrameworkSearchCriteriaInterface search = new MNC_Product_Sync.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1Service.FrameworkSearchCriteriaInterface();
        search.filterGroups = fgg;
        search.pageSize = 100;      
        nn.searchCriteria = search;

        try
        {
            var response = mage_client.catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1GetList(nn);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.